# Is it possible to ignore Http Content-Length?

Tags: java, crawler4j, http-content-length

I am using [Crawler4J](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) to collect information about a website. But sometimes I get the following error:

> INFORMATION: Exception while fetching content for: {someurl} [Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: X; received: Y]

(To me) it is not clear if it just happens if X < Y or vice versa, too.

The Exception is thrown in "fetcher.PageFetchResult.java" in fetchContent (I guess when getting the response headers).

So my question is: Is there any possibility to (generally) ignore the http content-length and get the information anyway?

I already looked up the crawler4j  issues but there is no similar problem.

Maybe somebody of the stackoverflow community has an idea how to solve this.

Thank you very much,

Hisushi

**EDIT**

Code (snippet) that throws this exception:

```
public boolean fetchContent(Page page) {
    try {
        page.load(entity);
        page.setFetchResponseHeaders(responseHeaders);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception while fetching content for: " + page.getWebURL().getURL() + " [" + e.getMessage()
                + "]");
    }
    return false;
}
```

responseHeaders and entity is null (by default):

```
protected HttpEntity entity = null;
protected Header[] responseHeaders = null;
```

Comment: I would say it only happens if X > Y. It will happen when fetching the response *body,* not the headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body` usually means you got disconnected from the server before reading the whole content length, just include a retry mechanism in your code so that you can try again and then get the full body.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked for me! I would like to vote this answer up but I need 15 reputation to do so :\